# Is there any other way to use mgoogleapiclient.connect() apart from onstart()

Tags: android, location, google-api-client, currentlocation

I'm developing an API for getting the currentlocation.
So how can i connect to GoogleAPiCleint from my java class(it's not an activity)

In other words do i've to connect to GoogleApiClient from OnStart only(Callbacks)

Comment: You need a `Context` to receive location updates. So it's not possible without an Android component, IMHO. This is an example for a location `Service`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30775807/4033690

Comment: yeah thanks for the conformation momo